# Ubuntu Login issue

Tags: 14.04, login, community

I am in great login issue in Ubuntu 14.04. in order to reduce bootup time I commented out default-display-manager text file as a root user found in directory `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` so that I'd be able to login in cli mode but after rebooting I'm not getting the login screen. What do I do now?

Comment: Couldn't you just edit it back, using your Ubuntu CD?

Comment: ok i try to do it

Comment: Reboot into recovery mode. And un-comment the line again. If you don't get a login prompt in recovery also, grap a life cd of usb and try it from a terminal there. .

Comment: You can still use virtual tty to login in system. User CTRL + ALT + Fn[1-7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your System, press `crtl + alt + f2`. Login at this TTY and comment it back in.
After a reboot everything should be fine.

Comment: thank you guys for helping me, last answer resolve the problem